# application re-open instead of browser when click on links in application

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking, url-launcher

In my flutter application I have enable deep linking.

Also in my application there are buttons that open links in the browser.

I am using  url_launcher: ^5.7.10 to open links in the browser.

```
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(
        url,
        forceSafariVC: false,
        forceWebView: false,
        enableJavaScript: true,
      );
    }
```

However on Android devices the user can go to application setting and configure always open the application if click on link say abc.com.

Or users can set "always open" option when a message popup.

This works fine if we click an a deep link.

But when we trigger a URL within the application, instead of opening the browser it re-open the application.

Is there a way to prevent this ....